# How can one enhance an unarmed striker?

Tags: dnd-5e

How can one enhance an unarmed striker?

Both D&D 5e Magic Weapon spell and Psionic Weapon (Mystic 3 Unearthed Arcana) only enhances a "weapon" and "Unarmed Strikes" apparently does not count as weapons.

What can I do? Any ideas I can think of to use for examples I cant post cause it will be flagged "make separate post since these seems to be different questions" though it still pertains to the original question.

Comment: No, it's fine to include examples that directly demonstrate what you're asking about. Just make sure they *are* directly demonstrating.

Comment: [Related](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/72277/15469), probably not a duplicate I think based on the details in that question.

Comment: Dale's answer raises a really important question - we need to know your character build to be able to tell what options will help you.

Comment: I'm building a Lv12 (Psionic) Mystic - Order of the Immortal via Mystics 3 UA.  Psionicaly Focused in Psionic Weapon discipline a weapon touched or unarmed strike deals psychic and magical damage. At 6th Lv add Str or Dex mod to psychic damage rolls. He also wants to travel light so he has Tavern Brawler feat and some Talents (cantrips) for ranged attacks. So he relies on unarmed strikes when it up close and personal. Augmented Weapon makes a "weapon" a +3 while concentrated on that Discipline. Other than Belts of X Giant Str or GoOPow, I don't know of any other way to enhance unarmed strike.

Comment: When you are downvoting answers because they aren't hitting requirements that aren't in your question, it's a sign you should expand your question so you can get answers that are helpful to you.

Comment: Jhyarelle, please edit that info, and any other requirements as mxyzplk suggested, into your question. We're not mind readers. If we don't know what specifically you're looking for then you *are* going to get answers that aren't helpful to your situation and we may not even be able to help you at all.

Answer (score 6):

**Play a Monk**

Unarmed strikes are the *raison d'être* of the Monk class. The damage they do scales with level, you can make an extra unarmed strike as a bonus action, you get extra attack at 5th level, they count as magical at 6th level, you can use Ki points in various ways to enhance their effectiveness.

Comment: @JhyarelleSilver what is a "solo class"?

Comment: @JhyarelleSilver so you mean not multi-class? If so then a single class monk fits your question perfectly.

Comment: The build is a level 12 UA Mystic with the Order of the Immortal archetype. Who just happens to be brawler combat wise with Tavern Brawler feat already in the mix. NVM, next question might help.

Comment: @JhyarelleSilver and where would I find that rather critical information in your question? I am perfectly happy that this is a good answer to the question you asked. If it is not an answer to the question you didn't ask that would be because you didn't ask it.