# Unarmed strike clarifications

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, feats, class-feature, unarmed-combat

I was wondering what D&D 5e feat, class and race abilities would affect *unarmed strike* from this list.
Mage Slayer, Savage Attacker, Sentinel, Rage, Reckless Attack, Brutal Critical, Frenzy, Improved Critical, most Manuevers, Divine Smite, Assassinate, Death Strike, Savage Attack (half-orc).

If any of these wouldn't work with *unarmed strike,* would they work with a natural weapon from something like *alter self*?

Lastly, are there any spells that would improve your unarmed strike?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking about [dnd-5e], but I wouldn't want to assume. What system are you using? If it is DnD5e, this may be a duplicate of [How can I increase my Monk's unarmed damage?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/72277/how-can-i-increase-my-monks-unarmed-damage)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I'll leave my close vote as-is, for now, as I still think this is a duplicate of [the question I linked above](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/72277/how-can-i-increase-my-monks-unarmed-damage). Could you take a look at that question, and maybe get back to us if it doesn't answer your question, and clarify why it doesn't?

Comment: @daze314 Not realy I would say that the link was helpful in a sense, but I'm still lost on things. What wording do abilities have to have or not have to  effect unarmed strike. Also I didn't see anything on if a natural weapon would change any thing. In fact now I wonder if monks can use the damage change on natural weapons.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast yes thank you. I am new to the stack exchange platform so the little italicized change was nice to learn.

Comment: Welcome, best wishes and glad to help. :)

Comment: Hi Lord Shadowheim, I've voted to put this question on hold because I think your last question "are there any spells that would improve an unarmed strike" is really a separate issue and belongs in its own post. I encourage you to [edit] the post to remove that part and ask it as a separate question if you want. Otherwise, this is a good question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Anything that works with a melee weapon atack will work with an unarmed strike. Of the things you listed, these work with unarmed strikes:

- Mage Slayer
- Savage Attacker
- Sentinel
- Brutal Critical
- Frenzy
- Improved Critical
- All Manuevers
- Divine Smite
- Assassinate
- Death Strike
- Savage Attacks

Rage and Reckless Attack are special; they worky with any melee weapon attack that is based on Strength. So they'll work with normal unarmed strikes, but if you are a Monk and choose to use Dexterity for your unarmed strikes, Rage and Reckless Attack will not apply.

All *Alter Self* does is make the damage of your unarmed strikes 1d6 of the appropriate type, make your unarmed strikes count as magical, and give you +1 to the attack and damage of your unarmed strikes. It does not change the way they work in any way that would affect any of the above.

Spells that improve unarmed strikes:

#### PHB

- Alter Self
- Banishing Smite
- Bless
- Blinding Smite
- Branding Smite
- Crusader's Mantle
- Divine Favor
- Ensnaring Strike
- Foresight
- Hex
- Holy Aura
- Hunter's Mark
- Searing Smite
- Staggering Smite
- Thunderous Smite
- True Strike
- Wrathful Smite

#### Elemental Evil Player's Companion

- Absorb Elements

Comment: Now what if you were a druid in the shape of a wolf and bite something would this list still be applicable to the bite

Comment: @LordShadowheim Like the first sentence of the answer - everything here is based on a melee weapon attack. Most natural weapons (wolf bites included) are melee weapon attacks, so everything here will apply to them. That's not true of *every* natural attack, although it's true of the majority.

Comment: doesn't Ensnaring Strike need to be with a weapon?

Comment: @LordShadowheim Nope, just requires a weapon attack. Unarmed strikes don't count as weapons, but they are (melee) weapon attacks.