# For non-monks, what is the interaction between mighty wallop on gauntlets and unarmed strike damage?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, weapons, unarmed-combat

If a character is not a monk, and therefore their base unarmed attack is considered to be neither a manufactured nor natural weapon, does casting mighty wallop or greater mighty wallop on their gauntlets increase their unarmed size category since their gauntlets affect their unarmed damage?

Mighty wallop states:
Mighty wallop increases the damage of a bludgeoning melee weapon by one size category without increasing the dimensions or weight of the weapon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask your DM.

You are combining two under-defined situations here, and there just is no good answer for either of them:

1. Your assertion that “therefore their base unarmed attack is considered to be neither a manufactured nor natural weapon,” is not actually supported by the rules—the rules don’t really say *what* unarmed strikes are, quite frankly. Sometimes they are treated as either, or both, or one or the other, or neither at all. Actually, most of the time, they’re just outright ignored.
2. [The entire situation with gauntlets is just a complete mess.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/30514/4563)

For my money, both unarmed strikes and gauntlets are listed in the “Weapons” table, and both are listed as dealing bludgeoning damage. That should be, in my opinion, quite sufficient for *mighty wallop*’s “bludgeoning weapon” requirement, for either of them. But you are going to have to ask your DM if they agree with me on that.

One could easily argue that

- in the English language, “weapon” refers to an object, and

  - the term is therefore equivalent to “manufactured weapon,” and that
- despite using all the rules for manufactured weapons and “manufactured weapon” not actually being a defined game-term, unarmed strikes can’t be “manufactured” per that word’s English-language definition,

  - so unarmed strikes don’t qualify as weapons, and then
- a gauntlet is “otherwise considered an unarmed attack,” so everything that’s true about unarmed strikes is also true about gauntlets,

  - barring explicitly those things listed there

    - (and *mighty wallop* isn’t).